# Passing arguments between @Composable functions in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
func A(str: String) {
    print(str)
}

func B() {
    A("Hi)
}
```

How I can do this in Jetpack Compose cause whenever I try to do this "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function" message is shown

Answer (score 2):

Each function which calls @Composable function have to be marked as @Composable too.
So you have to mark the both of functions as @Composable.

```
@Composable
func A(str: String) {
    print(str)
}

@Composable
func B() {
    A("Hi)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Composable` annotation before the second function and make it a Composable function.